# Creating Excel file without an Absolute (file) Path with Epplus

Tags: c#, .net, xml, excel, epplus

I've written an application that creates very simple Excel files with Epplus (five columns, and the only special formatting is a bold header column). The file is then moved by someone else, who imports it into a separate system, but the file is failing to import. I tracked down the reason for failure, and it is because the Excel file has an absolute path specified in workbook.xml. Excel's file validator warns of this issue, and telling Excel to delete the absolute path from the file's markup fixes the issue.

Does anyone know how to ensure that Epplus is not adding the file's absolute path to the file? Here's my code:

```
using (var pkg = new ExcelPackage(new FileInfo(path))) // "path" is an absolute path to a directory on a shared drive
{
     var sheet = pkg.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Manifest");
     var w = new ExcelWriter<ManifestLine>(sheet);

     // ... Write data ...

     await w.CloseAsync(Token).ConfigureAwait(false);
     pkg.Save();
}
```

Here's the workbook's markup: (the absPath needs to be removed)

```
<x:workbook xmlns:x15ac="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/spreadsheetml/2010/11/ac" xmlns:r="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships" xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" xmlns:x15="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/spreadsheetml/2010/11/main" mc:Ignorable="x15" xmlns:x="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/spreadsheetml/2006/main">
      <x:fileVersion appName="xl" lastEdited="6" lowestEdited="6" rupBuild="14420" />
      <x:workbookPr defaultThemeVersion="153222" />
      <mc:AlternateContent xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006">
        <mc:Choice Requires="x15">
          <x15ac:absPath xmlns:x15ac="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/spreadsheetml/2010/11/ac" url="Y:\ABC\Manifests\" />
        </mc:Choice>
      </mc:AlternateContent>
      <x:bookViews>
        <x:workbookView xWindow="0" yWindow="0" windowWidth="19065" windowHeight="9660" />
      </x:bookViews>
      <x:sheets>
        <x:sheet name="Manifest" sheetId="1" r:id="rId1" />
      </x:sheets>
      <x:calcPr calcId="0" />
    </x:workbook>
```

Thank you!

Comment: Is `path` a path to a directory or a path to a file?

Comment: @Quantic - It's a non-existant xlsx file (in a directory that does exist)

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't work well as a comment, so I'm posting an answer without testing it (because I can't test it):

```
// Save current dir before changing directories
var currentDir = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();

// Change to directory where the file is
Directory.ChangeDirectory(Path.GetDirectoryName(path));

// Pass in *only* the filename, not the whole path
// Because we changed to that file's directory the rest of the code should find it without needing the whole path
using (var pkg = new ExcelPackage(new FileInfo(Path.GetFilename(path))))
{
     var sheet = pkg.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Manifest");
     var w = new ExcelWriter<ManifestLine>(sheet);

     // ... Write data ...

     await w.CloseAsync(Token).ConfigureAwait(false);
     pkg.Save();
}

Directory.ChangeDirectory(currentDir);  // Change back to whatever directory the program was in before all this.
```